# Can't get objects from repository from Command

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I want to update some rows from table `comments`.

```
class TryCommentsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        //blah-blah-blah
    }

    private function update_comments($step_size, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
        $not_moderated_comments = $doctrine->getRepository('***Bundle:Comments')
            ->findBy(array('is_automoderated' => false))
            ->orderBy('c.date', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($step_size)
            ->setFirstResult(0)
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        for ($not_moderated_comments as $comment) 
        {
            $comment.setIsAutomoderated(true);
            $comment.save();
        }
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        self::update_comments(intval($input->getArgument('step')), $output);

    }
}
```

I'd write this command and try to run this, but got the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository' not found in C:\Users\.. ..\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory.php on line 75
```

How to fix it? How get entities from table?

UPD: My ***Bundle:Comments

```
namespace pv\***Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Comments
 */
class Comments
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $comment;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     * @return Comments
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your `***Bundle:Comments` entity?

Comment: It sort of looks like you added a repository attribute to your Blog entity but did not make the actual repository class.  Or maybe the repository is in the wrong spot or has a namespace typo.

Comment: @dmnptr I'd update question.

Comment: Do you mention `Blogger\BlogBundle\Repository\BlogRepository` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @dmnptr Damn me to hell for my carelessness!
I just forgot to remove this line from config.

Thank you very much!